# Size of the package

Tags: apt, package-management, file-size

Is there any way I can get the package size? I.e. if I am doing any installation, how much package (in MB's) size I have to download? How can I know ?

I know one way that is with:

```
jai@frank-Jai:~$ sudo apt-get install gedit
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  gedit-common gir1.2-gtksource-3.0 libgtksourceview-3.0-0
  libgtksourceview-3.0-common
Suggested packages:
  gedit-plugins
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gedit gedit-common gir1.2-gtksource-3.0 libgtksourceview-3.0-0
  libgtksourceview-3.0-common
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 985 kB of archives.
After this operation, 10.0 MB of additional disk space will be used
```

May I know the other ways ?